# Effective amplitude in Neutrinoless double beta decay

Tags: radiation, neutrinos

Can someone give me the value of the effective amplitude($A$) of  $\bar{\nu_\mu}\rightarrow\nu_\mu$ oscillation of Neutrinoless double beta decay? The expression is like this:
$A(\bar{\nu_\mu}\rightarrow\nu_\mu)= \frac{1}{E}\sum_{k=1}^3 [m_k(V_{\mu k}^*)^2e^{-iE_kt}]$

Comment: The masses of the free states are not knows (though Plank gave us a new, upper bound on the sum of the masses) and the mixing matrix is incompletely known ($\delta_\mathrm{CP}$ and both Majorana phases are unconstrained and both $\theta_{12}$ are $\theta_{32}$ are imprecisely known) so a numeric figure must be based on some set of assumptions.

Comment: @dmckee Is there any range of A so that i can be able to do some numerical calculation? Or is there any procedure to calculate A?

Comment: Not less than 0.5 fm nor more than the size of the nucleus (a few fm). Can you see why?